# JDK 8 and Windows 8.1

Tags: eclipse, java-8

I installed the JDK 8 64-bit for use with eclipse on a win 8.1 machine. I had an odd problem where my file browser kept crashing when trying to right click or open files. Chrome also frequently crashed.

It took me a while to figure out what was causing it. I got a different (new) PC with a new install of windows 8.1 x64 and the same thing happened as soon as JDK 8 x64 was installed.

It stopped after it was removed. I only have a few other things installed (VS2013, Steam, Nvidia drivers, Samsung Magician, Git, etc).

I tried installing JDK x32 which seemed OK at first, but eclipse was still looking in the x64 location. I tried restarting, but when the desktop was loading the whole desktop froze and took ages to respond. I uninstalled the JDK but my desktop is still freezing on startup.

After a few minutes it starts responding and works fine again....

I need eclipse for work and I have never seen anything like this before? Any idea what is happening or why it is now not responding at startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that we can find out what software causes incompatibilities on your system. However, it’s worth noting that Java can be used without modifying any system resources, if you are willing to sacrifice some of the comfort functions like having a Java control panel, the ability to launch runnable jars via double-click or the browser-plugin(s).

Most of these features are associated with the “public JRE”, so if you disable this feature during a JDK install, the installation should touch much less system resources. If that doesn’t help, you can go farther by just copying the jdk/jre folder from a different installation (having the same architecture) without going through any installation procedure. If you don’t have such second installation nor virtual machines to copy from, you may copy the installation folder from your machine to an unrelated folder, revert the system to the state before the installation (which doesn’t touch unrelated folders) and use the copy.

If Eclipse doesn’t find the Java installation folder then (not touching system resources implies not leaving a hint about the Java installation location), you have to modify Eclipse’s INI file to point to the Java installation location, as [said by Archimedes Trajano](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28866695/2711488). Alternatively, you may place the JRE right into a folder named “jre” within the Eclipse installation folder. Then, Eclipse will find it automatically.

Comment: Thanks, I was also hoping someone else would have had a similar problem at some point (lots of people here must use the JDK). I am wondering if it is to do with an old version of java somehow not installing properly (I think the Wacom drivers uses it).  I installed the new JDK before anything else this time and so far I have not run into any problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can set your JVM in the eclipse.ini
Generally I modify it to point to the jvm.dll of whatever JDK I am using so that I won't see eclipse.exe spawning off a java.exe process.  Instead it will just be all in one process.